# ionic 4 - SQLitePorter plugin is not installed

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, android-sqlite, ionic4

I followed this tutorial: https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-sqlite-queries/

I have a problem with the sqlitePorter plugin when I run this command on Visual Studio Code :

> ionic serve --devapp

The application starts correctly on my mobile, but the following error suddenly appears in my console:

```
console.warn: Install the SQLitePorter plugin: ‘ionic cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter’
console.error: [plugin_not_installed error]
```

I do not really understand what happens because when I do “ionic cordova plugin ls”, the plugin is present.

Does anyone have an idea of ​​what might be going on, and how can I fix that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic DevApp only supports a selective set of native plugins of which this plugin is not one of them.
If you wish to use this plugin, you need to do a full native build app using Ionic/Cordova.

For More Info: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter/issues/42